# Proof by Induction: Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

1. Prove with induction that |w^n| = n · |w|.

Ive tried to prove this statement with induction but am having trouble finishing it.

I think the base case is:  n = 0

|w^0| = ε(empty word) because w^0 = zero copies of w and 0 · |w| = ε

Here are some important definitions:
Exponentiation of words : w^i = i copies of w concatenated together                        concatenation of words : let w = abc and w' = ccc. then ww' = abcccc. ww' ≠ w'w
computing length of words  : |ax| = 1 + |x| if w = ax where a ∈ Σ and x ∈ Σ*  --------     |abc| = 1 + |bc| = 1 + 1 + |c| = 1 + 1 + 1 + |ε| = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3

Comment: What?  What sort of object is $w$?  Why do you think that $w^0=0$?  The empty product is generally defined to be equal to $1$, just as $\text{exp}(0)$ is equal to $1$... The statement sounds so incredibly wrong that you should have seen it as incorrect immediately.

Comment: w is some word. Maybe I shouldn't have used 0 but rather w^0 = ∈. because if some word, w, is copied 0 times would that not be the empty word? If its "incredibly wrong" please correct me

Comment: It still is not clear to me what w represents or what the cardinality is supposed to be in this context, but in most finite contexts it will be similar to exponents of natural numbers and plugging in a few values the proposed identity is false in most cases.  You say w is a "word".  How do you define exponentiation of a word?  The cardinality of a word?

Comment: 'w' represents some word. For example w = a is a word. w= abc is a word. the cardinality, |w|, of w=a is 1 and the cardinality of w=abc is 3. n is some integer. If w=a then w^2 = aa, if w=abc then w^2 = abcabc. w is concatenated 'n' times. I don't know how to explain this any more clearly

Comment: @puj please put this information inside your question, as it is an important detail, necessary to understand the question. Cardinality is used as the size of a *set*. Words / strings are usually seen as a sequence, so I would rather say it is the *length* of a word / string. Furthermore, since this has the set theory tag, do you consider only finite words, or also infinite ones?

Comment: I also expect that most of this exercise follows almost directly from the definitions that are given for (1) exponentiation of words, (2) concatenation of words and (3) computing the length of words. It might help if you provide these definitions as well, in case it doesn't follow as easily as I expect.

Comment: @Vsotvep Thanks I will remember to add all this info next time. I believe we are only dealing with finite words

Comment: Exponentiation of words : w^i = i copies of w concatenated together                        concatenation of words : let w = abc and w' = ccc. then ww' = abcccc. ww' ≠ w'w                                                                                                                              computing length of words  : |ax| = 1 + |x| if w = ax where a ∈ Σ and x ∈ Σ*       |abc| = 1 + |bc| = 1 + 1 + |c| = 1 + 1 + 1 + |ε| = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first prove that if $|wv| = |w| + |v|$ by doing induction on $|w| = n$.

Base case:  If $|w| = 1$ then $w = a$ for some character $a$ and $wv = av$ and $|av| = 1 + |v|$.

Induction: If $|w'v| = |w'| + |v|$ for all $|w'| \le n$ and if $|w|= n+1$ then $w = aw'$ for some character $a$ and so some word $w':|w'|=n$.

So $|wv| = |a(w'v)| = 1 + |w'v| =1+(n+|v|)= (n+1) + |v| = |w| +|v|$.

.....

Okay.  Now then

your proof.  $|w^n| = n|w|$.

Base case:  $|w^1| = |w|$

Induction.  If $|w^n| = n*|w|$ then $|w^{n+1}|= |ww^{n}| =|w| + |w^n|=|w| + n*|w| = (n+1)*|w|$.